# Why Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Price is not getting overridden in live site?

Tags: module, magento-1, price, magento-enterprise, filter

I'm working with Magento EE 1.12.0.0

In one of my modules I have overridden Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Price and it works perfectly fine in my localhost, but when I install the same module in my live site, it doesn't  work.

That means

> all the files are getting overridden except
>   "Royal_Filters_Block_Catalog_Layer_Filter_Price" which extends
>   Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Price

my config file:

```
<global>
...
<blocks>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <layer_state>Royal_Filters_Block_Catalog_Layer_State</layer_state>
                <layer_view>Royal_Filters_Block_Catalog_Layer_View</layer_view>
                <product_list_toolbar>Royal_Filters_Block_Catalog_Product_List_Toolbar</product_list_toolbar>
                <layer_filter_attribute>Royal_Filters_Block_Catalog_Layer_Filter_Attribute</layer_filter_attribute>
                <layer_filter_price>Royal_Filters_Block_Catalog_Layer_Filter_Price</layer_filter_price>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
...
</blocks>
...
</global>
```

All the other four classes are overridden but not the last one.

Also my other modules work good and fine.

My live site is exactly the same as in my localhost.

But still live site
uses Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Decimal. can I override Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Decimal instead of Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Price, will it work?

Comment: Make sure you spelled the files & folders name correctly. `Royal/Filters/Block/Catalog/Layer/Filter/Price.php`. If your local machine is on windows (that is case insensitive for file names) and the live site is on linux (case sensitive) you might get these kind of issues. Check the log folders also. Also check it there is an other extension overriding the same block.

Comment: @Marius: alright I'll check that "case sensitivity" thing first.

Comment: @Marius, please post your assumptions as a questions. First of all even if they are not a case here it can still be a solution for someone else who has this problem. And the second, we need higher answers per question rate to pass a public beta :-)

Comment: @everyone, don't be afraid to post answers which will be guaranteed accepted. they are still valuable.

Comment: @Tim: ok I will post my asumption as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually my live site use Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Decimal for price filter, so overriden that class to achieve what I need.

my config.xml

```
<global>
...
<blocks>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <layer_state>Royal_Filters_Block_Catalog_Layer_State</layer_state>
                <layer_view>Royal_Filters_Block_Catalog_Layer_View</layer_view>
                <product_list_toolbar>Royal_Filters_Block_Catalog_Product_List_Toolbar</product_list_toolbar>
                <layer_filter_attribute>Royal_Filters_Block_Catalog_Layer_Filter_Attribute</layer_filter_attribute>
                <layer_filter_decimal>Royal_Filters_Block_Catalog_Layer_Filter_Decimal</layer_filter_decimal>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
...
</blocks>
...
</global>
```

and I extend Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Decimal in my Block

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you spelled the files & folders name correctly. `Royal/Filters/Block/Catalog/Layer/Filter/Price.php`. If your local machine is on windows (that is case insensitive for file names) and the live site is on linux (case sensitive) you might get these kind of issues. Check the log folders also. Also check it there is an other extension overriding the same block.
**[EDIT]**
Magento EE has a set of blocks for the layer filter. Maybe one of them is used in your case.
Here is an example: `Enterprise_Search_Model_Catalog_Layer_Filter_Price`.
Activate the template path hints with block class names also, and see what type of block is used for rendering the price filter.

Comment: it uses Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Decimal. can I override Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Decimal instead of Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Price, will it work?

Comment: There is only one way to find out :). Try it.

Comment: all right, i'll override with Decimal class, but i wonder, why does magento behave in such a weird manner?

Answer (score 0):

Quite possible you have an extension on a remote host which you don't have locally and this extension also overrides `Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Price`.

In this case the solution (not quite nice though) may be to extend this extension's class instead.